# How to check for one word per line in a file using fgets

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I am pulling words from a file but I need to check if the file follows a specific format.
"The source file format is one word per line. If a line does not follow that format, then it should be skipped" My code is not checking for this and I have no idea how I would even begin its just pulling one line no matter what and strtok it word by word. please help me. Im a beginner.

I tried using an if statement to check for new lines and I couldn't seem to get it to work maybe I just had it in the wrong place.

```
const char *get_word_from_file(FILE *file)
{

        char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN]; // inner one is the outer most view
        char buf[MAX_LINE_LEN];
        size_t idx = 0;

        while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file))
        {
                char *word = strtok(buf, " ?.,\n-\"");
                while (word)
                {

                        strncpy(words[idx], word, sizeof(words[idx])); // Destination, src, size of destination to prevent overflow
                        word = strtok(NULL, " ?.,\n-\"");
                        ++idx;
                }
        }
        fclose(file);
        srandom(time(NULL)); // seeding with current time
        // generating a random number and picking a word from words array
        int random_number = random() % idx;
        char *random_word = words[random_number];
        // Allocating memory for the word
        char *verified_random_word = allocate_word_memory(random_word);
        return verified_random_word;
}
```

Comment: Start by doing a minimal version of the code that does not include all kinds of random stuff that you don't even talk about, and that makes an attempt at doing a check. Focus on one problem at a time. The time to advance to more difficult stuff is when you do understand.

Comment: @Cheatah unfortunately this is kinda what I was given to modify I just don't understand how i would check the line I get from fgets for only one word. sorry if its alot first post kinda desperate.

Comment: Throw away all code. Make a simple program that does only does the thing that you want. You don't advance until you have solved that isolated problem.